# How can I know the working directory under FileChooserListView structure if no file is selected

Tags: python, kivy, working-directory

I am new to python kivy, recently I am using kivy to build up my android app,
the question is below:

I am using the FileChooserListView to show all the file system in the my boxlayout, I know that when I select one or more file, I can use some_filechooser.path to obtain the current working directory.

## test.kivy

```
BoxLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    orientation: "vertical"
    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        path: "./"
        on_selection: root.selected(filechooser.path)
```

Afther I touch/click/select one file,
on_selection: root.selected(filechooser.path) is executed to obatain the current path of the selected file, but can I do the same thing even if no file is selected.
Thanks for all your help

Comment: You can, but you'll need to execute a function or schedule a event to execute some piece of code to do it. For instance, create a test button and hook a `on_click` to it that executes `print(App.get_running_app().root.some_filechooser.path)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filechooser.path` to display the current working directory when no file is selected.

## Snippet

```
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Working Directory:'
            Label:
                text: filechooser.path
```

## FileChooser » Path

> path
>
> path is a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) and defaults to the current working
>   directory as a unicode string. It specifies the path on the filesystem
>   that this controller should refer to.

You can do the following:

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

import os


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()


class Editor(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

Root:
    text_input: text_input

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: 'Load'
                on_release: root.show_load()
            Button:
                text: 'Save'
                on_release: root.show_save()

        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: text_input
                text: ''

            RstDocument:
                text: text_input.text
                show_errors: True

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 90

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Working Directory:'
                Label:
                    text: filechooser.path

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Filename:'
                Label:
                    text: ''.join(map(str, filechooser.selection))

            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text: "Cancel"
                    on_release: root.cancel()

                Button:
                    text: "Load"
                    on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)
```

## Output

[image: FileChooser - path]